# Want to upgrade my Dell OS to Windows 8 or 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, windows-8, updates

I have been using 1525 inspiron since 2008 sept, i am considering upgrade to windows 8 or maybe 7. the machine is fantastic and in a very good working, never ever had any problem except for battery change which i just did a couple of months back. I tried searching a lot for the upgrade but havent found any. Is there a way by which i can upgrade the OS.

Thnaks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from Vista to Windows 7 you can see this [Microsoft  answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/upgrade-vista-32-to-windows-7-64bit-on-a-dell/c4859b4a-a6fb-46e5-ab16-49c3ffae8242). And for Windows 8 you can download [Microsoft  upgrade assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) to check whether your system is able to upgrade Windows 8 or not.

And [Dell community](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19474494.aspx) says that they have not the drivers for the Windows 8 yet, while most of the drivers of Windows 7 are working on Windows 8, but some are not with different models.